# I want to allow certain file types on dokan upload files

Tags: plugins, php, functions, uploads

Before we get started, I have tried alloweding "UPLOAD_UNFILTERED_FILES" thing on config.php and i have tried allow different mime type plugins, none of them worked

I want to allow .rbxlx, .rbxlm, .rbxl which are text/xml files for Roblox.

Currently if I make a downloadble product on my Dokan Website and upload a file with .rbxl file extention it says "Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type.".

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, so others can review and not post unhelpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try allowing mimes yourself, like this :

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
function custom_upload_mimes($existing_mimes) {
    $existing_mimes['rbxlx'] = 'text/xml'; 
    $existing_mimes['rbxlm'] = 'text/xml'; 
    $existing_mimes['rbxl'] = 'text/xml'; 
    return $existing_mimes;
}
```

If this doesn't help, you need to look outside WP - it's possible the server itself won't allow those uploads. Can you access the .htaccess ? If so, you can try adding this :

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/xml .rbxlx
    AddType text/xml .rbxlm
    AddType text/xml .rbxl
</IfModule>
```

If not, you can try contacting your hosting.